# Можно ли во Flask-е посылать HTTP GET запрос с телом?

Tags: python, flask

Пытаюсь научиться принимать в GET-методе тело с данными, но почему-то у меня ничего не приходит.

Вот код:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def get_test_data():
    print('\nrequest:')
    print(request)
    print('request.data:')
    print(request.data)
```

А вот код теста:

```
import unittest
from flask import url_for
from proba import app  

class ProbaTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app_ctx = app.app_context()
        self.app_ctx.push()
        self.client = app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.app_ctx.pop()

    def test(self):
        self.client.get(url_for('get_test_data'),
            data={'username' : 'user1', 'password' : 'pass1'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Получаю:

```
(env) d:\Projects\python-workspace\proba>python manage.py test
test (proba_test.ProbaTest) ...
request:
<Request 'http://localhost/test' [GET]>
request.data:
b''
ok
```

Моя основная цель: Выдавать информацию по моим ресурсам только тем, кто зарегистрирован.

Для этого пишу декоратор, в котором идет проверка переданных в запросе `username` и `password`. А это минимальный пример повторяющий мою ситуацию.

Прошу подсказать что я делаю не так?

**UPD**:
В комментариях было сказано, что в GET нельзя посылать тело. Есть на эту тему обсуждение в англоязычной версии stackoverflow: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: Если вы нашли решение вопроса, можете его оформить в виде ответа.

Comment: @Timofey Bondarev: Нет, не найден.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением моей проблемы является применение метода request.get_data() вместо request.data.

Есть достаточно подробное пояснение в англо-язычной версии [Get raw POST body in Python Flask regardless of Content-Type header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999990/get-raw-post-body-in-python-flask-regardless-of-content-type-header)

Answer (score 3):

get-запрос отличается от post запроса как раз тем, что у get-запроса нет тела. поэтому нужно либо пользоваться либо post-запросом, либо передавать ваши данные в get-параметрах, типа

```
self.client.get('{0}?username=user1&password=pass1'.format(url_for('get_test_data')))
```

Comment: А как же тогда HTTP Auth работает? В заголовках?

Comment: @sys_dev Да, клиент отправляет HTTP-заголовок `Authorization` с (обычно) закодированным в base64 паролем.
(А авторизацию на сайтах, если что, принято делать через cookies и работающие поверх них сессии, во Flask такой функционал я вроде видел.)

Comment: @andreymal: Чтобы понять свою проблему. Мне прежде всего надо понять можно и в GET-запросе посылать тело, да или нет? Судя по той ссылке что привел после UPD - можно. Возникает вопрос: почему у меня не посылается?

Comment: @sys_dev потому что по стандарту нельзя. И по той ссылке про это написано. И, может быть, кто-нибудь в коде урезает это самое тело, стараясь соответствовать стандарту. Наверно, можно найти какие-то обходные пути и это тело прочитать, но всё же не надо так делать — стандарт запрещает.